# CSS (Mobile version of site) Sliding Menu via swipe

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a mobile sliding (**not slide-in**) menu similar to how google.com menu is on mobile devices (as shown below).

[image: Google.com menu items scrollable from left-to-right]

Notice the menu there allows you to slide from left to right to show the hidden menu items (Books, etc. in this case). I would like to create this effect. Can it be done with pure CSS or is there a plugin for it?

I would like overflowing elements to be hidden at the left but a swipe should be able to bring them into focus.

My menu code looks like:

```html
<div id="nav-wrapper">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#option1">Option1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#option2">Option2</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#option3">Option3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried

```css
#nav-wrapper {/* max width and height set here to hide the scroll bars of the <ul> */}
.nav-tabs {width: 300px; overflow-x: scroll; white-space: nowrap;}
```

problem with the code is that the overflowed `<li>` elements go into a new line and are hidden.

I'm using bootstrap and AngularJS by the way.

Comment: "I've been trying to figure out how to get this done for quite a while now and have tried a few things." What doesn't work?

Comment: can you edit your question and hit CTRL + M and paste what code you have tried in the box?

Comment: @Whymarrh I've tried setting a max width to the <ul> and putting overflow: scroll; while hiding the scroll bars - problem with this is that the overflowed element doesn't stay in the same line.

Comment: better to include what you've done so far. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `li` elements need to be displayed as inline-blocks. Use `::-webkit-scrollbar-` to customise the scrollbar in Webkit/Blink browsers on desktop. Set a max-width on the wrapper, make sure the `ul` is set to display as a block element and has **no width constraints**.

In the demo below, the width of the container is arbitrary; I just chose 400px to demonstrate the overflowing.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5guzupzd/

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar { width:0; height:0 }
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { background: transparent}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track { background-color: transparent}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
#nav-wrapper {
  border:3px solid #444;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
ul,li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0
}
.nav.nav-tabs {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* apply iOS momentum scrolling effect to this element */
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap
}
.nav.nav-tabs li {
  display: inline-block
 }
.nav.nav-tabs li a {
  display: block;
  background: mediumblue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 16px
}
```

```html
<div id="nav-wrapper">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#option1">Option1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#option2">Option2</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#option3">Option3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've added this code but for some reason, my overflowing <li> elements still dropdown (and are hidden) to the next line. Is there anything specific I should be looking for that can cause this?

Comment: Hey, nvm I found the issue. I had float: left; set on the <li> tags. Removed that and it's working great! thank you so much.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: Oh, don't forget to add `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to apply iOS's momentum scrolling effect to this.